How to name the roles created by aws sam
I have a lambda function
AuthFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      PermissionsBoundary: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:policy/ci
      FunctionName: !Sub 'authorizer'
      CodeUri: dist/lambdas/authorizer/
      Policies:
        - !Ref ApiGeneralPolicy
        - PolicyName: authFunctionPolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - ssm:GetParameter
                Resource: !Sub
                  - arn:${AWS::Partition}:ssm:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:parameter${ParameterName}

I want to name the role created by the aws from these policies. Because the PermissionBoundary allows the createRoles action only on resources arn:aws:iam::{accountId}:role/ci*. So, how can I name the role?
I don't want to create a separate role resource because I have more than 20 lambdas, creating the roles resources separately is hard to manage and read. So, I need inline policies.
Is there any way to create inline roles under the function itself ?
